# How To Put Multiple KeyEvents In One If Statements

Tags: java

I wrote a passcode program, you chose 4 numbers and when you press those four numbers nothing happens, if you press one of the four numbers then the home screen pops up. But what I need is for the computer to take all four numbers see if it matches with the code I decided and then show the home screen. Any suggestions?

```
if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_3))
{

    if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_9))
    {
        if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_1))
        {
            StdDraw.picture(0.27,0.5,"Homescreen.jpg",1,1);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `||` (or) operator in boolean statements.  So something like `if (isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_9) || isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_1)) { ...` should work.

Comment: I did , but it would only take one key event instead of 4 if I do that way.